# Missing entitlements file for WatchOS 2 Extension

Tags: ios, watchkit

My iOS app share data with Today extension with App Groups. I am also sharing my data from iOS app with WatchOS 2 extension via WatchConnectivity and it is working. However, if I don't enable App Groups both in WatchOS Extension and WatchOS App, I get the following warning;

`Missing entitlements file for target Appwatch Extension: <file location>`

If I enable App groups, for WatchOS targets, warnings go away. Even though I don't use App groups for WatchOS part, should I enable it? Thanks

Comment: Entitlements file is exist? If you don't use App Groups, entitlements file is required in some cases. (e.g. keychain)

Comment: I use Keychain with app groups with iOS and Today Extension. However I don't have any intention to use Keychain or app groups on WatchOS part. So should I remove Entitlements.plist file from WatchOS targets and compile? Or add those properties to Entitlements.plist file even though I don't use them on WatchOS? Thanks